# jQuery - placing content within a random div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've 252 li's, their IDs defined by numbers between 1 and 252. What I'm trying to achieve is replacing text within a random li every time I click a h1. Yet this doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
$('h1').click(function() {
    var flashNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 251) + 1);
    $('#'+flashNumber).html('test');
});
```

Comment: Nothing wrong AFIACS http://jsbin.com/kudehug/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Can you post HTML code?

Comment: Is this javascript loaded from an external file or in the same html page?

Comment: Works here https://jsfiddle.net/jrw5p2cg/

Comment: Given that the fiddle ^^ works, we need to see your HTML

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o7d6ju4u/ I guess it has something to do with the fact that the <li>'s are  empty? I want them to be empty, however. I also see that I erroneously typed div in my initial post. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. If your HTML is also just a list of `<div>`s, then I can only see one potential problem - the name of your `div#id`s. Prior to HTML5 they **had to start with a letter**. What doctype are you using? Maybe it behaves differently in different browsers?

Try adding a letter to your id names:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('h1').click(function() {
    var flashNumber = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 251));
    $('#my-divs-' + flashNumber).html('test');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Click</h1>

<div id="my-divs-1"></div>
<div id="my-divs-2"></div>
<div id="my-divs-3"></div>
<div id="my-divs-4"></div>
<div id="my-divs-5"></div>
<div id="my-divs-6"></div>
...
<div id="my-divs-251"></div>
```